# Read the signing certificate of the running application from code

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, x509

I have an application which I sign with a PFX certificate via Visual Studio 2013.

I want to read this certificate from inside the application. I'm guessing I have to use reflection.

I've already tried to get it from the manifest per:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
X509Certificate x = a.ManifestModule.GetSignerCertificate();
```

but still `x` remains `NULL`.

How do I read the certificate?